# Why did composer downgrade my packages?

Tags: php, composer-php

`php composer.phar update` did this (removed 2.3.0 packages and installed entire 2.2.5 Zend Framework):

```
$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-filter (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-view (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-loader (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-log (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (2.3.0)
  - Removing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.3.0)
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.5)
    Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Why did it do that?  My composer.json looks like this and suggests nothing of the sort that directed the above course of events:

```
"repositories":[
    {
        "type":"composer",
        "url":"https://packagist.org/"
    },
    {
         "type":"composer",
         "url":"http://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
"require": {
    "zendframework/zend-log" : "2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-escaper" : "2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-filter" : "2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-view" : "2.*"
}
```

My expectation was:  remove 2.3.0, install 2.3.1 packages

Comment: Was anything changed (added/removed) in your dependencies before running `update`?

Comment: Either way; the moral of the story is to be *as specific as possible* with your version numbers.  So use `~2.3` (which would be `>=2.3` and `<3.0`) or `2.3.*`.  Composer goes through a bunch of logic to find out which set of versions fulfills all of your dependencies.  If you are more specific, then you just need to update your `composer.json` if you decide you want a new version.  It takes out some of the "chance" of the `update`.

Comment: Is that your full `composer.json` ? are you requiring something else that has the zend set to lower then what you have defined?

Comment: it is pretty much the entire composer.json (minus the name, description and license). I do not think that anything was moved/altered inside the JSON

Comment: @Sam yay!  changing it to `~2.3` worked!  Feel free to use your comment as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer doesn't quite describe *why* it was downgraded, since the algorithms in Composer are quite intensive (that is why `update` takes way longer than `install`ing with a `.lock`).  They go through all of your dependencies, all of the potential versions, and what each dependencies' versions' dependencies are.  After getting all of this information it tries to come up with a "perfect" match.

Sometimes the slightest change in your dependencies, or a dependency's dependencies, can create drastic changes.  Also, you'll sometimes see that it is impossible to resolve your dependencies because one dependency may require `symfony/http-foundation ~2.5` and one may require `symfony/http-foundation 2.1.*` (this isn't what happened in your case, but it is good to know).

All in all, the moral of the story is you should be as specific as possible with your `composer.json` (especially in production).  That way, you can always be in control of what version you use rather than letting Composer decide.  Worse case, is you run a `composer update` and it cannot resolve your dependencies.  Then do some research on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) to see which versions will happily resolve together.

I suggest using either version `~2.3` (which is the same as `>= 2.3` and `< 3`) or `2.3.*`.  Then Composer won't even try version `2.2.5`.  Check [Composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions) to see how you can express different package versions.